# How to adjust node labels of a triangle?

Tags: pstricks, pst-eucl

Problem 1:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,newcent}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-node,pst-func,pst-plot,pst-eucl,pstricks-add,multido}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=true](-2,-2)(3,3)
\pstGeonode[PosAngle={50,100,90}, PointSymbol={*,x,*},
PointNameSep=3mm, CurveType=curve,

PointName={\alpha,\beta,\gamma,default}] %%% <<----

(-2,0){alpha}(-1,-2){beta}(0,-1){gamma}(2,-1.5){T}

\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Question 1:

**Why it haven't must been " (-2,0){\alpha}(-1,-2){\beta}(0,-1){\gamma}(2,-1.5){T} "**

Problem 2:

[image]

See the following:

```
\pstTriangle[PointSymbol=*,%
  PosAngle={0,45,180},  %% <<---- No effective
  PosAngleA=0,PosAngB=45,PosAngleC=180, %% <<---- Works fine.
linecolor=blue,linewidth=1.5\pslinewidth](1.5,-1){A}(0,1){B}(-1,-.5){C}
```

Question:

**Why?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That are two different things: a printed point name and an internal node name. It can be the same but must not by default. `\alpha` is a macro and can be a printed point name, but *not* a node name unless you say `\string\alpha`. Otherwise `\alpha` will be expanded to  `\mathchar"10B` for example. However, `\string\alpha` wouldn't be a useful node name.

`PosAngle={10,20,30}` is only valid for `\PstGeonode`. For a triangle use `PosAngle=10, PosAngleB=....`

Comment: For question 1, its mean only with the math symbols, we always  use the first syntax.

Comment: Yes, but it makes no difference to say `(-2,0){alpha}(-1,-2){beta}(0,-1){gamma}(2,-1.5){T}` or `(-2,0){a}(-1,-2){b}(0,-1){g}(2,-1.5){T}`  Any possible name without a _backslash_